# JAVAFX application closes

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

```
package login;

public class loginAppController implements Initializable {

    loginModel loginModel = new loginModel();

    @FXML
    private JFXButton loginButton;
    @FXML
    private Label dbStatus;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField email;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField password;
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<option> combobox;
    @FXML
    public Label loginStatus;


    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        if(this.loginModel.isDatabaseConnected()) {
            this.dbStatus.setText("Connected To Database");
        } else {
            this.dbStatus.setText("Not Connected To Database");
        }

        this.combobox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(option.values()));
    }

    @FXML
    public void Login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (this.loginModel.isLogin(this.email.getText(), this.password.getText(), ((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString())) {
                Stage stage = (Stage) this.loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
                switch (((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString()) {
                    case "Admin":
                        adminLogin();
                        break;
                    case "Student":
                        studentLogin();
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                this.loginStatus.setText("Wrong Data");
            }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
        }
    }



    public void studentLogin() {
        try {
            Stage userStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane root = (Pane) loader.load(getClass().getResource("/Users/Alar/Desktop/SMS/src/main/resources/students/studentFXML.fxml").openStream());
            StudentsController studentsController = (StudentsController) loader.getController();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            userStage.setScene(scene);
            userStage.setTitle("Student Dashboard");
            userStage.setResizable(false);
            userStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void adminLogin() {
        try {
            Stage adminStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane adminroot = (Pane) adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Users/Alar/Desktop/SMS/src/main/resources/Admin/Admin.fxml").openStream());
            AdminController adminController = (AdminController) adminLoader.getController();

            Scene adminscene = new Scene(adminroot);

            adminStage.setScene(adminscene);
            adminStage.setTitle("Admin Dashboard");
            adminStage.setResizable(true);
            adminStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter login data, I debugged it and the application jumps from

```
Pane adminroot = (Pane) adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Users/Alar/Desktop/SMS/src/main/resources/Admin/Admin.fxml").openStream());
```

to

```
catch (Exception localException) { }
```

and it won't open the new window. The same happens for `studentLogin()`.

Comment: What do you mean by catch the real one?

Comment: i mean: localException.printStackTrace(); inside catch block

Comment: then it throws this
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at login.loginAppController.adminLogin(loginAppController.java:100)
 at login.loginAppController.Login(loginAppController.java:61)`

which are exactly 2 rows i sent:
`                Pane adminroot = (Pane) adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Users/Tu/Desktop/SMS/src/main/resources/Admin/Admin.fxml").openStream());
`

Comment: and ` adminLogin();`

Comment: @TheDumbest That means your path is wrong.

Comment: @TheDumbest important info like stacktraces should be included in the question itself. [Edit] a question to add this kind of info.

Comment: *Never* use empty catch blocks. How do you expect to be able to know what is going wrong if you suppress all the error messages.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

`getResource`'s parameter is the path in the classpath. If you're using a jar, it matches the name of the entry of the resource data in the jar file. You're using a file path though.

Furthermore it's better to use a url as location to load the fxml, since this allows you to use resources relative to the document location ([attribute values with prefix `@`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution)).

```
FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Admin/Admin.fxml"));
Pane adminroot = (Pane) adminLoader.load();
```

If the path in the above snippet does not work, adjust the path according to the location of the resource relative to the classpath root.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your path is wrong, try to change your line to:

```
public void adminLogin(){
        try {
            Stage adminStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane adminroot = (Pane)adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Admin/Admin.fxml").openStream());
            AdminController adminController = (AdminController)adminLoader.getController();

            Scene adminscene = new Scene(adminroot);

            adminStage.setScene(adminscene);
            adminStage.setTitle("Admin Dashboard");
            adminStage.setResizable(true);
            adminStage.show();



        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

}
```

Comment: that doesnt work as well. it throws
`javafx.fxml.LoadException: unknown path:11`